# <css> tag in .css or other files

Tags: html, css, web

I was going through some legacy code (circa 2010) and discovered a `<css>` tag in `.css` file. Code looks something like that:

```
// styles.css
<css>
body {font-family:arial; font-size:12px; margin:0; }
td {font-family:arial; font-size:12px;}
.stroke {background:#CCCCCC;}
[.......]
</css>
```

As I understand, this `css` file is non-legitimate and not to standard. At least, `<css>` or for that matter any other tags should not be present in `.css` files.

I couldn't find any `<css>` tags in W3C or any such tag mentioned in google's searching. Is it some legacy (6+ years) thing or just a mistake of the original developer?

Comment: You could always run it trough the w3c validator: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ I have never seen it before. It is definitely not necessary and probably invalid.

Comment: I tried Googling that element to see if it existed a long time ago in a galaxy far far away, and I'm pretty sure it has never existed before. Looks invalid to me.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, because web langauges are very flexible, and by flexible, I mean you can throw anything at them and they take it.

I guess it is either a type error, or a copy right trap like Agloe was.

Answer (score 0):

If you want add CSS styles in a index.html you don't use the tag `<css>` but the tag `<style type="text/css">`. And yes, it's a mistakes use `<css>` 
If you want know other about it you can read on MDN [tag style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style)

Comment: i know about `<style>` of course. It is just that I've never in my life seen it before

Answer (score 0):

It is just an error. The CSS is invalid. You can confirm this with [a validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input) (although you'd have to remove the `//` section first since CSS doesn't have any kind of single line comment syntax so that will also error).